# How to add story points to tasks in Jira Cloud

Tags: jira, story-points

I'm not sure if this forum is best for an administrative question on jira but here goes.

I currently have an instance set up on Jira Cloud and I'm unable to configure my tasks to show story points.

I would expect to see them under `Assignee` Below you have a task without points and a story with points.

[image: Task without points][image: Story with points]

If I attempt to configure either one I'm redirected to the `Scrum Default Issue Screen` which contains the `Story Points` as a value in the context fields

[image]

What do I need to do to add points to tasks?

Comment: Welcome to PM.SE. The question is too specific to Jira software and, as Sarov mentioned in his answer, the Atlassian community is a better place to raise this jira setup question. I'm puzzled, however, on why would you want to have Story Points on a Task. That's the kind of question the community can help you out :)

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Select the Jira icon > Jira settings > Issues.
> 2. Under FIELDS, select Custom Fields.
> 3. Find the Story Points Field and note the Issue type(s) that are associated with it.
> 4. To allow Tasks (or Bugs) to use Story Points open the three dot menu and select "Configure".
> 5. Under the heading "Default Configuration Scheme for Story Points" select "Edit Configuration".
> 6. Finally, find the heading "Choose applicable issue types" and select the Issue "Task" issue type is selected (along with Stories and Epics).

Source: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Adding-and-showing-story-points-for-tasks/qaq-p/964536